# Landing due to low fuel

Tags: landing, emergency-procedures, fuel-consumption

If an aircraft has to make emergency landing due to critically low fuel. Who is responsible pilot or maintenance crew?

Comment: Are you adding about a specific country or regulations?

Comment: Reponsible for what?  For landing the plane?  For assigning the blame?  For taking the blame?  For making sure it doesn't happen again?  You mean who is at risk of a certificate enforcement action, or jail time, or being fired, or being fined, or not being promoted anytime soon?  Responsible in the eyes of the FAA or equivalent authority, or in the eyes of airline or the FBO renting the plane, or in the eyes of a jury when a passenger sues for emotional distress?   The question is very broad and open to interpretation.

Comment: Also maybe unforecast fog was responsible, or the enemy aircraft that shot holes in the fuel tanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flight crew is responsible for ensuring there is enough fuel on board before taking off.

Further, they are required to check the fuel consumption en route at regular intervals to ensure there is enough fuel to continue. If fuel is consumed at a higher rate than expected, perhaps due to headwinds, the crew will divert to another airfield before the fuel runs too low.

Ground crews will load up however much fuel the captain tells them to. As long as they do that they are not responsible for any mishaps during the flight.

Answer (score 2):

The Captain is ALWAYS responsible, even when it's not his fault.

Comment: It's his fault to have failed to check.

Comment: What do you mean by "responsible"? If Captain Bob is flying an airliner and a bulkhead explodes due to improper maintenance, in what sense and in what way is Bob responsible for this?

Comment: @TannerSwett he took off with an aircraft that wasn't airworthy. That's his responsibility, technically. In reality he'll often be cleared of blame if the problem was impossible for him to detect, but unless that can be shown he's responsible.

Comment: Is the captain responsible in any *practical* sense or only in a theoretical, ceremonial sense? (Like how the dollar bills in my pocket constitute a debt that the Federal Reserve Bank owes to me, but only in a theoretical, ceremonial sense, since there is no way to get them to *pay* this debt.)